# c++ why ranges::find_if is so fast

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

I changed this code:

```
auto it = chunks_.begin();
for (;; ++it) {
  if (it == chunks_.end()) {
    chunks_.emplace_back();
    alloc_chunk_ = &chunks_.back();
    break;
  }
  if (!it->is_filled()) {
    alloc_chunk_ = &*it;
    break;
  }
}
```

to this:

```
auto it = std::ranges::find_if(
            chunks_, [](const auto &chunk) { return !chunk.is_filled(); });
if (it == chunks_.end()) {
   chunks_.emplace_back();
   alloc_chunk_ = &chunks_.back();
} else {
   alloc_chunk_ = &*it;
}
```

and in both gcc 11.2 -O3, MSVC 19.32 /Ox, the second version was almost 20 times faster. (there was no other code change)

`chunks_` is `std::vector<Chunk>`, and `chunks_.size()` was approximately 500, and the loop was executed for roughly 100,000 times. The first code was about 500ms, the second code was about 30ms (including all other codes, so clearly this part was the bottleneck)

These are `Chunk`s:

```
struct Chunk {
    // ... other details ... 

    [[nodiscard]] bool is_filled() const { return !blocks_available_; }

    unsigned char data_[num_blocks_];
    unsigned char first_available_ = 0;
    unsigned char blocks_available_ = num_blocks_;
  };
```

Why the compiler optimizes `std::ranges::find_if` so fast?

Comment: Does `std::find_if` have similar efficiency of `ranges::find_if`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I think ```std::find_if``` is slower (both gcc and msvc). The first version was about 500ms, ```std::ranges::find_if``` was about 30ms, I feel ```std::find_if``` is about 40~45ms (repeated only dozens of times, so not 100% accurate)

Comment: Two things. First did you test everything in release build with optimizations on? And second I think it is because ranges will not use an iterator (which may involve copying during operator++)

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes of course, in debug build the comparison becomes 600ms (the first code) vs 320ms (```ranges::find_if```)

Comment: Ok I was just wondering :) You could also put your codesnippets on https://godbolt.org/ and check for differences in the generated assembly. Maybe that will give a clue.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think I got a clue, in the fastest code it just traverses the contiguous memory where ```chunks_``` resides and just checks every 257th byte. (```num_blocks_``` is 255 and ```sizeof(Chunk)``` is 257, ```alignof(Chunk)``` is 1). In the first code it uses a pointer (as the iterator) and dereferences the pointer every time. The compiler seems not to be able to optimize the first code yet

Comment: Interesting, and the somewhat unfortunate chunk size probably plays a role too

Comment: @frozenca Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Compiler optimization issues are very hard to analyze, if you only provide code snippets. There should be a complete yet minimal example that showcases the difference you mentioned, and makes it reproducible for anybody.

Comment: I put your code into an online benchmark and it showed the [opposite behavior](https://quick-bench.com/q/AgSjPaU0eU-7ry6K4-o0cpEVQ14). You should also provide the details for the Chunk class if necessary.

Comment: @JakobStark The problem was that my gcc/MSVC were incompetent. In wandbox gcc 12.1,  they are equally performant. this is ```ranges::find_if``` (https://wandbox.org/permlink/kucntk9CyS1lrmz1) and this is the first version code (https://wandbox.org/permlink/kIsU4YSfuQFGv6UG). Microsoft should do their job better... (I still seeing the first version code extremely slow in MSVC 19.32 /Ox)

Comment: In general, you shouldn't expect MSVC to do as good a job at optimizing as clang or gcc.  It's well known (or at least a long-standing fact) that it tends to miss more optimizations than gcc or clang.  https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=1015

Answer (score 3):

Most of difference is because of the time used for checking. In both example you have two check points: 1.  `if (it == chunks_.end())` and 2. `if (!it->is_filled())`.

The first example does this checks for every element of the container, (in worst case) but in the second example, the second check (inside the find function) is done for all elements of the container (again in worst case) but the first check is done just for the found iterator. I think you can change the code to follow same course. Then the difference should be minimized.

In addition the find algorithm uses range based for loop which is slightly faster than conventional for loops.

Edit:
range based for-loops are syntactic sugar, has no impact on performance.
Thanks to Morgan.

Comment: Agree, performance difference should be due to the added if-statement in the loop. However, range based for-loops are syntactic sugar, has no impact on performance whatsoever. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for